# Remove Avatar isn't working for me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, avatar

The Remove Avatar checkbox isn't doing anything for me on my edit form. Here is my code.

_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@child, html: { multipart: true}) do |f| %>

  <% if child.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(child.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this child from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% child.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>


    <%= f.label :name %><br />
     <div class="field"><%= f.text_field(:name) %> <br /></div>

    <%= f.label :balance %><br />
     <div class="field"> <%= f.text_field(:balance) %> <br /></div>

    <%= f.label :parent_id %><b> ID</b><br />

     <%= f.number_field :parent_id, :value => current_parent.id, :readonly => true %><br />

     <%=f.label :avatar %><br />
     <%= image_tag(@child.avatar_url) if @child.avatar? %>
     <%= f.file_field(:avatar) %>
     <%= f.hidden_field(:avatar_cache) %>
     <br />
     <label>
     <%= f.check_box :remove_avatar %>
     Remove Avatar
     </label>

  <div class="actions">
    <% if @child.new_record? == true %>
    <%= f.submit("Add Child") %>
    <% else %>

    <%= f.submit("Save Child") %>
    <% end %>
  </div>


<% end %>
```

Child Controller

```
class ChildrenController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_parent!
  before_action :set_child, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  # GET /children
  # GET /children.json
  def index
    @children = Child.all
  end

  # GET /children/1
  # GET /children/1.json
  def show

  end

  # GET /children/new
  def new
    @child = Child.new
  end

  # GET /children/1/edit
  def edit
  end




  # POST /children
  # POST /children.json
  def create
    @child = Child.new(child_params)
    if @child.avatar.file.nil?
      img = LetterAvatar.generate(@child.name, 200)
      File.open(img) do |f|
        @child.avatar = f
      end
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @child.save
        format.html { redirect_to @child, notice: 'Child was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @child }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @child.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /children/1
  # PATCH/PUT /children/1.json
  def update
    if @child.avatar.file.nil?
      img = LetterAvatar.generate(@child.name, 200)
      File.open(img) do |f|
        @child.avatar = f
      end
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      if @child.update(child_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @child, notice: 'Child was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @child }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @child.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /children/1
  # DELETE /children/1.json
  def destroy
    @child.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to children_url, notice: 'Child was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_child
      @child = Child.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def child_params
      params.fetch(:child, {}).permit(:name, :balance, :parent_id, :avatar)

          # params.fetch(:user, {}).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone, 
    end
end
```

If I click save with the Remove Avatar box checked, it literally does nothing to the avatar, if I go back to any page that displayed the avatar, it is still there. What am I doing wrong? I am using Ruby on Rails 5.0.1

Side note: I am aware of some of the deprecated things that are being used here, such as before_filter. I am working with a large group of people so not all of this code is mine, fixing it is not priority at the moment.

Comment: Could you show your controller's code? You can remove `== true` from `<% if @child.new_record? == true %>`

Comment: Ok, I edited in the controller code. Also not all of this code is mine I am working with a group of people and we are all basically Rails novices.

Comment: Looks like `:remove_avatar` is not present in the strong params. Could you try adding it?

Comment: Thanks that worked, I didn't think of it before because it was nowhere in the readme on GitHub and normally leaving that kind of thing out gives me errors, rather than just not doing anything.